# Unmarshal JSON nested field values into struct fields

Tags: go

```
// Given the following struct:

type MyStruct struct {
  First  string
  Second string
  Third  string
}

// I would like to unmarshal the following JSON into MyStruct such as:

bytes := []byte({ { "first":  { "href":"http://some/resources/1" },
                    "second": { "href":"http://http://some/resources/2" },
                    "third":  { "href":"http://some/resources/3" } })
var s MyStruct
err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &s)

fmt.Println(s.First) 
  // how do I make this return "http://some/resources/1" instead of 
  //   "map[href:http://some resources/1]"?
```

What I'm looking for is something like a combination of go field tags with actual JSON object notation where I would be able to declare `MyStruct` like this:

```
type MyStruct struct {
  First  string   `json:"first.href"`
  Second string   `json:"second.href"`
  Third  string   `json:"third.href"`
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json package doesn't support a way to access nested fields (unlike encoding/xml). So you will either have to write you own Unmarshal function (see: [JSON decoding in go](http://attilaolah.eu/2013/11/29/json-decoding-in-go/)) or encapsulate the fields with accessors.